# Wobbly Windows in 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, compiz, windows, opengl, ccsm

I enabled wobbly windows in CCSM but nothing is happening.

Comment: Are you using 11.04 or 11.10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running `unity --reset`, and logging out and logging in. Ensure that Wobbly Windows is still enabled.